# How gracefully restart Sphinx search daemon after reindexing

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I've reindexed my Sphinx search with `/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --all --rotate` and renamed my original index output files to something else. Simply changing the index argument passed to `$sphinx->Query($query, $index);` returns no results.

I suspected the daemon doesn't know the new index files exist. So I ran

`sudo /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd`

again to try to restart it. But it threw

`FATAL: failed to lock pid file '/usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable (searchd already running?)`

I had to `kill` the 2 processes of the search daemon and start it again to grab from the new index files. Is there a graceful way to restart it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but just so you know, to 'restart' Sphinx, you need to stop it then start it (as in, two distinct processes).

To stop it, call `searchd --stop` then just start it again with `searchd`.

Comment: Imho `/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart` is better

Comment: The command `/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch restart` appears to be distribution-specific.

Comment: Building on @Narcissus answer, you can wrap up both calls in a shell script

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to call indexer on the new index to create it and then --rotate to update it.

So it would be something like

```
indexer --config /path/to/config.conf indexname
```

And then when you just want to update your indexes

```
indexer --config /path/to/config.conf --rotate --all
```

This will create a temporary copy of each index and replace the old ones when finished. 
For more info on what actually happens see http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#ref-indexer

On the other error your getting 
Do

```
ps aux | grep searchd
```

if it returns no results, then remove /usr/local/sphinx/var/log/searchd.pid
and start searchd again

Answer (score 4):

It seems there is an issue with the `searchd --stop` command failing to stop the daemon on some instances of Sphinx.

Try: `service sphinxsearch stop`

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sphinxsearch/+bug/990395

Comment: In my case I run into this because of having nonstandard pid file in `/etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf` - which was different from  `/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

`service searchd start` worked for me on CentOS